# Anypoint MQ Connector - Difference between Consume and Subscriber

Tags: mule-studio, mulesoft

Anypoint MQ Connector has two modules, **Consume** and **Subscribers** that could be used to retrieve messages from the queue. I cannot find any good documentation about what is the difference between the two and uses cases where one should be preferred over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consume is an operation and Subscribe is a message source, both provided by the Anypoint MQ connector.

[Subscribe](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/anypoint-mq/3.x/anypoint-mq-listener) polls the queue to find if there are new messages available, and then starts the flow with the message read. You can not use Subscribe inside a flow.

[Consume](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/anypoint-mq/3.x/anypoint-mq-consume) is an operation that is used inside a flow. Because it is not a message source it can not start a flow, like Subscribe. Instead you use when the flow is started by some other source, like an HTTP request, then you want to read a message from a queue in some place of the flow execution.